# SQL Prompt error

Tags: sql, redgate, red-gate-sql-prompt

I tried two versions of Redgate SQL Prompt, but there are no result, with SQL Server 2014 no version works. Here is the error:

> The loading of the 192.xxx.xx.xxx server failed because of Database version 12.00.2000 not supported

Can anyone tell me if there is any solution?

Comment: I have SQL Prompt 7.0.0.42 and it works **flawlessly** with SQL Server 2014 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which versions have you tried? SQL Prompt has supported SQL Server 2014 from around version 6.2/6.3-ish if I recall correctly. They're up to version 7.0 now, which definitely supports SQL Server 2014 because I'm using it right now on a 2014 server :)

Comment: Now I am downloading SQL Developer Bundle 2015 and will try